# Is it possible to get the assets used in iOS built-in controls?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

Is it possible to get the assets (the PNGs) used in some iOS built-in controls like the slider, switch or stepper?

Comment: Even more interesting: Any chance one would be allowed to use them in their own apps?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with the [UIKit Artwork Extractor](https://github.com/0xced/UIKit-Artwork-Extractor) which runs in the iOS Simulator and produces a directory with the files on your desktop.

Comment: Wow, that extractor is freakin' amazing! Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

You may get them with a jailbreaked iPhone, or using an app that lets you access the iPhone filesystem from you Mac/PC, like DiskAid.

But you can also find PSD files with all the iOS GUI elements on the web, like:

- http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/iphone-4-gui-psd-retina-display/
- http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/ipad-gui-psd/

Guess this will be easier...